# Using a Service Worker in Vue3 SPA to manage an access to API's static files

Tags: vuejs3, openid-connect, service-worker, vite, static-files

All internal requests from my web SPA (Vue3) to my RestAPI (Django Rest Framework) are generated by using HTTP Header `Authorization: Bearer <access-token>`. There `access-token` is the token from my OpenIdConnect Auth Server (Keycloak). All works fine - I'm able to manage access to API's resources.

But I've run into one specific task:

The requests from SPA's web pages to any static files (images, PDF, HTML) are generated directly by user's browser - not by my vue-js-code. That's why I'm not able to add any HTTP-header to these requests. And I'm not able to control user's access to static files from HTML-tags like:

`<img src="/my-static-store/foto.jpg">`

`<iframe src="/my-static-store/document.pdf"></iframe>`

`<iframe src="/my-static-store/document.html"></iframe>`

User's browser doesn't include any authorization headers in its requests.

So, any user can get an access to the static file if he know (or guess) the name of that static file.

My current task is get solution for including `Authorization` HTTP header in browser's requests. This header must include an access-token, generated by the OpenId Connect module of my Vue App. And one important detail: access token is always refreshing in the SPA (about each 5 minutes).

I've found a nice [article](https://www.twelve21.io/how-to-access-images-securely-with-oauth-2-0/#:%7E:text=4.%20USE%20SERVICE%20WORKERS). The author gives the good analysis of different approaches. And the first 3 ways are not good for me for some reasons (I would like to explain in comments if need). But the last one seems to be the most perfect for my project. It is based on the leveraging **Service Workers**. Service worker allows to "learn" modern browser to include custom HTTP headers in requests. It is not a main idea of service workers, but a nice feature of PWA (progressive web application).

I've tried this solution (using [vite-pwa](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/guide/)) and it seems to be a working way. My browser actually starts include any custom HTTP header. But I got stuck on next step: I don't figure out how to pass actual access-token to the Service Worker. I can hard-code test access-token in my service worker's code, but I can't pass the access tokens from OpenId Connect module of my App to the service worker.

In other words: how to make dynamic "communication channel" between my Vue3 SPA code and Service Worker? I need to pass periodically refreshed access tokens from my web-app to service worker.

If you give me any other advice for my global task (access control to static files) I will be happy as well!

**Update:**
I've find the possible solution. I try to use [message event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/message_event) approach to pass tokens to SW. And it seems to be a working way. But I was struggling with some nuances. I had to register the Service Worker for my web app scope, NOT for remote RestAPI URL scope. If I did second I ran into problem: requests from `<iframe>` tags are handled properly, all works fine. But requests from `<img>` tags are not passed through Service Worker! For example if I put URL of requested image into `<iframe>` element the request is handled by SW. But! If I use `<img>` element with the same image`s URL - the request doesn't intercepted by Service Worker.

Ok! Now I got a working solution for my task! Yeah!!!!